# npm ERR! must provide string spec

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having this error since a while, in this case, the problem occur executing the following command.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Actually, it happens with any npm commands as well, I tried deleting package.json, changing npm versions and yet didn't work, so I'm here asking for help.

This is the entire error:

```
C:\Users\c>npm install

npm ERR! must provide string spec
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\c\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-28T16_50_23_009Z-debug.log
```

Version of npm and node:

```
node --version
v16.13.2

npm --version
8.3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it was a missing version in my `package.json`

look like mistakenly I removed some text

```
 "dependencies":{
   "angular/cli" :"{}"
  }
```

Comment: Same issue here: "@angular/cdk/coercion": null,

Answer (score 0):

try to update your npm: npm upgrade
then: npm clean cache

Comment: upgrade command does not work, the same error happens, and clean cache makes no difference. Though thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Following, i'm in the exact same position. Tried changing the NodeJS version using NVM and now some of the commands work (npm -v shows im running 8.1.0) but npm update and npm/npx create-react-app give me an " ERR! must provide string spec " !

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reactivate an old project which had packages noted down differently then usual in `package.json`. They had an `id` and `locator` parameter, like:

```
"ImagePicker": {
  "id": "ImagePicker",
  "locator": "https://github.com/dhavalsoni2001/ImagePicker.git"
}
```

After removing / replacing them by version numbes, i could install.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this same issue yesterday.

This is what I did to resolve it:

- Uninstalling node entirely and removing `node_modules` and `package.lock.json` from the project directory.
- Install node afresh and run `npm install` in your project directory.